# stands for an escape from the zero-sum game of Victorian social codes, at the price of such amenities of civilization

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the part in italics. I have no idea what message the writer is trying to convey. I'd appreciate an explanation on this.

Another important metaphor for Maggie is the
gypsy queen, a fantasy that Eliot realistically and humorously
undercuts. The myth of the gypsy camp, which Eliot
along with Bronte and other Victorian novelists adapted
from romantic poetry and painting, *stands for an escape
from the zero-sum game of Victorian social codes, at the
price of such amenities of civilization* as tea, books, and
groceries. Maggie's contact with this world, briefer, more
disillusioning, and more humiliating than Jane's experiments
with rebellion, is instructive.

[A literature of their own, Elaine Showalter](https://books.google.com/books?id=E5j7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=%22Another%20important%20metaphor%20for%20Maggie%20is%20the%20gypsy%20queen,%22&source=bl&ots=BqnkXMhtmf&sig=ACfU3U27WS1lLjyu0WhMs8rT8NzqsxRyVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU5tKd2ePtAhXnUBUIHVpvBJsQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Another%20important%20metaphor%20for%20Maggie%20is%20the%20gypsy%20queen%2C%22&f=false)

Comment: In today's terms, the "Gypsy camp" metaphor is perhaps an alternative lifestyle without the luxuries of television, fast food and cell phones. The antithesis of the known life; the excitement of stepping outside one's normal restrictive existence and mores.

Comment: This is a request for an explanation of the **subject matter** of one particular text. Such an explanation is unlikely to illuminate any general features of the **language**.

Comment: A zero-sum game is any interaction in which someone must lose whenever anyone wins. The winning and losing balance out, hence the "zero sum" metaphor. Not all games are zero-sum, so escaping from one is worthwhile if possible. But escape may be difficult; one has to give up the good with the bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessary to repeat the definitions of game that may be found easily, for example, in

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/game)

The use of the word here is similar to that of Eric Berne in his book *The games people play*

> [Penguin Books](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/459/4596/games-people-play/9780241257470.html)

Life is seen as a game that involves a mix of entertainment, rules and competition.

Victorian social codes are seen as rigid and convention-governed rules for the game of life. In such codes, transactions may be economic, social or emotional but every transaction is controlled by convention, every gain is balanced by a loss, everything has a price. This is the zero-sum game: one man's gain is another's loss; even one's own gain may be balanced by one's own loss. There is little room for free personal expression, for ungoverned adventure, for reckless generosity of spirit or body, for the exploration of hormone-driven emotions.

In contrast to this, Maggie as the gypsy queen of a gypsy camp stands for an imagined alternative, one in which the Victorian rules do not apply, where there is more uninhibited freedom, more personal expression, more colour, more emotion (perhaps by implication, more sex?). There is the possibility of risk, reward, loss and all those chance things that the Victorian code tried to exclude from its tightly structured view of society.

Hardy recognizes that these imagined freedoms of the fantasy gypsy camp come at a price: if we drop too many conventions we also lose many of the benefits of civilized society, the reliable supplies of books tea and groceries upon which we rely.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. It seemed an interesting question, combining many notions.